# Error while syncing Exchange Web Services in Silverlight application

Tags: synchronization, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Currently I have developed a Silverlight application which synchronizes Email and its corresponding folders between Exchange and my Silverlight application.  I use EWS for ExchangeOnline and I have encountered a problem with synchronization, from time to time it fails..

Here is my setup/scenario of how I got it all configured:
API Name: SyncFolderHierarchy, SyncFolderItems
Targeted features: synchronization emails and folders with exchange server

Scenario description:

- create a object of ExchangeService with:

  ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1
  EnableScpLookup = false,
  TraceEnabled = true,
  Credentials = new WebCredentials(_exchangeEmail, _exchangePassword)
- using AutodiscoverUrl for get account url
- Call SyncFolderHierarchy/SyncFolderItems for sync and get a error message (time to time on different folders)

**Other Considerations:**

When I run my application it sends about 7 requests every 30 seconds. Unfortunately sometimes I get an error. While on the other hand it does successfully sync two times every 5 minutes (about).

Please see below for **error details**:

- folders sync:

  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: An internal server error occurred. Try again later.
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.SyncFolderHierarchy(FolderId syncFolderId, PropertySet propertySet, String syncState)
- folder items sync:

  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: An internal server error occurred. Try again later.
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest1.Execute()
  at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.SyncFolderItems(FolderId syncFolderId, PropertySet propertySet, IEnumerable`1 ignoredItemIds, Int32 maxChangesReturned, SyncFolderItemsScope syncScope, String syncState)

**So, my questions are:**

- Is there something in my  setup/configuration what might be the reason of these failures from time to time?
- Is there a possibility to look into online exchange logs?

**Any help would be highly appreciated.**

Thanks in advance,
Dmitry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure why, but the problem disappears by itself (maybe it was temporary problem on exchange server).
According to some internet posts - this can be an issue with throttling.